# Please find the error in here. After clicking the button the words appears and dissappears in the box

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
    <button onclick="myFunction()"> Click Me</button>
    <br>
    <hr>
    Words:<br>
    <input type= "text" id= "randomNumber">
</form>

<script>
        function myFunction(){
            var randomWords = ['Alpha','Beta','Gamma','Epsilon','Kappa','Omega'];
            var callNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
            var randomWord = randomWords[callNumber]
            document.getElementById('randomNumber').value=randomWord

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

'If you can then please remove the input box and print the words separetely'
the result blinks in the box and then dissappears.

Comment: button is a submit button by default and submit buttons submit so the form is submitting....

Comment: Can you please elaborate and if possible tell me the correction

Comment: cancel the click action or set the type to button

Answer (score 0):

The `<button>` is submitting the form. Move the button outside the form, [prevent the form from submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), use a different trigger element than `<button>`, etc. The issue is that the form is submitted (i.e. the page is reloaded) as soon as the button is clicked and the function is ran.

```js
function myFunction(e){
  var randomWords = ['Alpha','Beta','Gamma','Epsilon','Kappa','Omega'];
  var callNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
  var randomWord = randomWords[callNumber]
  document.getElementById('randomNumber').value=randomWord
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()"> Click Me</button>
<form>
    <br>
    <hr>
    Words:<br>
    <input type= "text" id= "randomNumber">
</form>
```